# How to support a nested open complex type in the OData C# driver?

Tags: c#, odata, edmx

I am using the following C# OData packages, in a .NET Web Api project:

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData
>   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData

When following Microsoft's example [Use Open Types in OData v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4), everything seems to work as expected, as long as the open type does not contain additional nested open complex types.

This means that this will work fine:

```
public class WplController : ODataController
{
    private List<AbstractMongoDocument> _documents = new List<AbstractMongoDocument>
    {
        new AbstractMongoDocument
        {
            Id = "2",
            Meta = new MongoMeta(),
            Data = new MongoData
            {
                Document = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"root_open_type", "This works!" },
                }
            }
        }
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<AbstractMongoDocument> Get()
    {    return _documents.AsQueryable();}
}
```

While this throws an exception

```
public class WplController : ODataController
{
    private List<AbstractMongoDocument> _documents = new List<AbstractMongoDocument>
    {
        new AbstractMongoDocument
        {
            Id = "1",
            Meta = new MongoMeta(),
            Data = new MongoData
            {
                Document = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"root_open_type", "This works!" },
                    {"nested_open_type",  new Dictionary<string, object>() //Nested dictionary throws exception!
                        {
                            {"field1", "value2" }, 
                            {"field2", "value2" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<AbstractMongoDocument> Get()
    {    return _documents.AsQueryable();}
}
```

The exception is as follows:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred
>
> Message: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'.
>
> Message: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.OData.dll
>
> Additional information: The given model does not contain the type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

---

This can be fixed by adding the following line to the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
builder.ComplexType<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

However, this leads to the following OData response JSON:

```
 {
      "@odata.context": "http://localhost:50477/odata/$metadata#wpl",
      "value": 
      [
           {
                "Id": "1",
                "Meta": {},
                "Data": 
                {
                     "root_open_type": "This works!",
                     "nested_open_type": 
                     {
                          "@odata.type": "#System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary_2OfString_Object",
                          "Keys": 
                          [
                               "field1",
                               "field2"
                          ]
                     }
                }
           }
      ]
 }
```

How can I make sure that ODate properly serializes the nested open fields as well? I.e. I would like the following resulting OData JSON:

```
 {
      "@odata.context": "http://localhost:50477/odata/$metadata#wpl",
      "value": 
      [
           {
                "Id": "1",
                "Meta": {},
                "Data": 
                {
                     "root_open_type": "This works!",
                     "nested_open_type": 
                     {
                          "field1": "value1",
                          "field2": "value2"
                     }
                }
           }
      ]
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any potential help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm in the same boat as you. I need to expose some data as pure JSON. This is a working solution using the `ODataUntypedValue` class. It serializes to what you would expect. I tested it with your models and mine.

Implement a `MongoDataSerializer` class:

```
public class MongoDataSerializer: ODataResourceSerializer
{
    public MongoDataSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes the open complex type as an <see cref="ODataUntypedValue"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graph"></param>
    /// <param name="expectedType"></param>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    /// <param name="writeContext"></param>
    public override void WriteObjectInline(
        object graph,
        IEdmTypeReference expectedType,
        ODataWriter writer,
        ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
    {
        // This cast is safe because the type is checked before using this serializer.
        var mongoData = (MongoData)graph;
        var properties = new List<ODataProperty>();

        foreach (var item in mongoData.Document)
        {
            properties.Add(new ODataProperty
            {
                Name = item.Key,
                Value = new ODataUntypedValue
                {
                    RawValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value),
                },
            });
        }

        writer.WriteStart(new ODataResource
        {
            TypeName = expectedType.FullName(),
            Properties = properties,
        });

        writer.WriteEnd();
    }
}
```

Implement a `CustomODataSerializerProvider` class:

```
public class CustomODataSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    private readonly MongoDataSerializer mongoDataSerializer;

    public CustomODataSerializerProvider(
        IServiceProvider odataServiceProvider)
        : base(odataServiceProvider)
    {
        this.mongoDataSerializer = new MongoDataSerializer(this);
    }

    public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.FullName() == typeof(MongoData).FullName)
        {
            return this.mongoDataSerializer;
        }

        return base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }
}
```

Register the `CustomODataSerializerProvider` in your `Startup.cs`:

```
        app.UseMvc(options =>
        {
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
            options
                .MapODataServiceRoute(
                    "odata",
                    "odata",
                    b => b
                            .AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Scoped, s => model)
                            .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(
                                Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Scoped,
                                s => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odata", options))
                            .AddService<ODataSerializerProvider, CustomODataSerializerProvider>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
        }
```

This is the output using your models (note the property names begin with a lower case letter because I enabled `ODataConventionModelBuilder.EnableLowerCamelCase()`):
[image: Working output]

Comment: I am no longer working on the project that this was needed in, so I can't verify whether this answer is correct. If anyone has verified that this works, feel free to notify me, and I'll accept the answer as the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've accepted the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Dictionary<string, object>` as an open complex type may be confusing the builder. Open types need to define a property that contains the dynamic properties. In the case of `Dictionary<string, object>`, it seems to think that the `Keys` collection is the dynamic property container for the open type. Try creating a type to define as the complex type, something like the following:

```
public class OpenComplexType
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Then register it as a complex type:

```
builder.ComplexType<OpenComplexType>();
```

Finally, define your `Document` property using `OpenComplexType` as the type:

```
public class MongoData
{
    public OpenComplexType Document { get; set; }
}
```

I am by no means an expert with the WebAPI OData libraries, and there may be other ways to work around this by using `Dictionary<string, object>`, but this should be a place to start.