# ASP.NET core OData: Serialize class containing dictionary to JSON, dictionary becomes array of key value pairs. Need it to be an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

*Edit: turns out this has something to do with being on an `OData` controller. Adding OData configuration below, from startup.cs.

Disclaimer: I don't have time tonight to make a true minimal reproducible version of my code. I've just pulled the OData settings out of my larger project. Sorry! I'll try to circle back on Monday and create a true minimal reproducible version.

I'm trying to return a JSON in this basic format:

```
{ "Name": "hello", Props: { "a":"1", "b":"2" }}
```

`Props` is a Dictionary, and if I move this code to a "normal" controller, it works as expected. But on the OData controller, it's serializing the Dictionary as an array of objects, like this:

```
[ { "Key": "a", "Value": "1"}, ...]
```

I think the OData configuration below is all I'm doing, and I don't believe I've tried to override any JSON serialization settings.

Simple version of controller code:

```
public class SuperObject{
  public SuperObject(string name){ 
    Name = name;
    Props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  }
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Dictionary<string, string> Props {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult SimpleGet(int key)
{
  var x = new SuperObject("hello");
  x.Props["a"] = "1";
  x.Props["b"] = "2";
  return Ok(x);
}
```

Startup.cs related to OData configuration:

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => {
  routeBuilder.Select().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
  var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
  builder.EntitySet<RecordFile>("RecordFile");
  var coll = builder.EntityType<RecordFile>().Collection;
  fn = coll.Function("SimpleGet").Returns<SuperObject>();
  fn.Parameter<int>("key");

  var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
  routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
}
```

Comment: Show how you do the serialization. Because typically -- unless you specified something different -- Newtonsoft.Json does serialize a Dictionary to `{"a": "1", "b": "2"}` See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RWzRRs  Your output looks more like the serializationresult of a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: Right. By default it does exactly what you need - without array. I bet you have something in serializer settings now, which causes such behavior

Comment: Ah yes, you're right...I'm trying to do this on an `OData` (`Microsoft.OpenApi.OData`) controller, and it hadn't occurred to me that it might be related to that. But when I moved it to a "normal" controller it serializes correctly. Seems strange, but must be something to do with `OData`.

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682776/how-to-support-a-nested-open-complex-type-in-the-odata-c-sharp-driver/57647035#57647035)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `JsonConvert.Serialize()` method and log the serialized result before you send it.

I tried to replicate your issue in a console app, but I didn't get any unexpected results like you did. This means that you are probally doing something wrong elsewhere. Think about other mistakes that maybe give you an unexpected output like:  If your application is .NET Core 3.0 or later => Did you tell your application to use Newtonsoft with the `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` extension method in `Startup.cs`

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new SuperObject("appel");

            obj.Props["a"] = "5";
            obj.Props["b"] = "10";

            var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonText);
        }

        public class SuperObject
        {
            public SuperObject(string name)
            {
                Name = name;
                Props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> Props { get; set; }
        }
```

Output: (as expected)

```
// {"Name":"appel","Props":{"a":"5","b":"10"}}
```